# Tem como fazer um PIVOT utilizando SUBSTR

Tags: query, pl-sql, oracle11g

Olá pessoal tudo bom? Estou tentando fazer um PIVOT no oracle 11 pegando somente o primeiro caractere de uma STRING.

```
CREATE TABLE T_ESTOQUE(
    CD_ENDERECO VARCHAR(15),
    CD_PRODUTO VARCHAR(20),
    QT_ESTOQUE INT
);
INSERT INTO T_ESTOQUE VALUES ('206K07000', '189909.01058889', 12);
INSERT INTO T_ESTOQUE VALUES ('206K08300', '189909.01058889', 20);
INSERT INTO T_ESTOQUE VALUES ('206K09300', '190909.01058889', 10);
INSERT INTO T_ESTOQUE VALUES ('101X03000', '188895.01054611', 13);
INSERT INTO T_ESTOQUE VALUES ('109T24000', '108483.18020015', 29);
INSERT INTO T_ESTOQUE VALUES ('102D20300', '190850.01030003', 44);
INSERT INTO T_ESTOQUE VALUES ('502D20300', '192457.01030003', 15);
INSERT INTO T_ESTOQUE VALUES ('502C05000', '180240.01030353', 35);
INSERT INTO T_ESTOQUE VALUES ('902D02200', '190156.01030016', 15);
INSERT INTO T_ESTOQUE VALUES ('903F01100', '188350.01030038', 10);
```

> Queria jogar essa query abaixo em um PIVOT

```
SELECT 'G' || SUBSTR(CD_ENDERECO, 1, 1) AS "GALPAO",
        SUM(QT_ESTOQUE) AS "TOTAL"
FROM T_ESTOQUE
WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(CD_ENDERECO, '([X])')
GROUP BY SUBSTR(CD_ENDERECO, 1, 1)
ORDER BY 1
```

> O que eu já tentei fazer porém sem êxito

```
SELECT * 
FROM
        (SELECT  SUBSTR(CD_ENDERECO,1, 1),
                       QT_ESTOQUE                       
                FROM T_ESTOQUE
        )
PIVOT
        (SUM (QT_ESTOQUE)
        FOR SUBSTR(CD_ENDERECO, 1, 1) IN ('2')
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

> Boa noite pessoal! conseguir resolver meu problema vou postar para
> caso alguém tenha o mesmo problema que tive.

```
WITH T_TEMP AS (
                   SELECT 'Total' AS "GALPAO",
                                 'G' || SUBSTR(CD_ENDERECO, 1, 1) AS T_GALP,
                                  QT_ESTOQUE
    FROM T_ESTOQUE
    WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(CD_ENDERECO, '([X])')
    )
    
    SELECT * FROM T_TEMP
    
    PIVOT
    (
    SUM(QT_ESTOQUE)
    FOR T_GALP IN ('G1', 'G2', 'G5', 'G9')
    )
```